# Luxon date creation

Tags: javascript, datetime, luxon

I want to create luxon date from

```
 Thu Jul 15 04:21:42 EST 2021
```

for which I'm using

```
let a = DateTime.fromFormat(
      'Thu Jul 15 04:21:42 EST 2021',
      'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy'
    );
```

but it is not creating an expected date. Can anyone please help me to figure out what went wrong?

Comment: You have two issues: "EST" is not a valid offset and "ZZZZ" is not a valid [token](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/parsing?id=table-of-tokens). Offset tokens and formats are Z (e.g. +5), ZZ (e.g. +05:00) and ZZZ (e.g. +0500). EST is an abbreviation of a civil timezone name, for which there is no standard and many are ambiguous (e.g. IST might be one of 3 different timezones). Consider replacing EST with -05:00 and use token ZZ.

Comment: ok thanks will do same